# GXT: Highlight the search phrase for a StoreFilterField

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a TreeGrid with a correspondig TreeStore and a StoreFilterField. Filtering works really well.
But as I search for the filter string across multiple columns, it would be much clearer to the user why a line is filtered if the filter string would be highlighted in the grid. Something like this:

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to accomplish this? I did not found anything for it in the API (https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gxt-4.0/index.html?help-doc.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was to write a custom `render` method for your `Cell`. But you also need the information about your search string so I think you better overwrite the `getRenderedValue` method of your [`GridView`](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gxt-4.0/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/grid/GridView.html). Of course no finished solution but an approach.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I'll look into that.